# How to solve Mixed Content blocked error in Vuejs + Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, frontend, backend

I deployed frontend and backend in a shared hosting.
When I call api, then shows this errors in browser console.

```
xhr.js:210 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://front.thecomicden.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://back.thecomicden.com/api/allTask'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
```

**Vuejs  method**

```
created(){
            this.axios.get("http://back.thecomicden.com/api/allTask").then(Response=>(this.tasks=Response.data.allTask))
        },
```

**Laravel Api Routes File**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\TaskController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});


Route::get('/allTask',[TaskController::class, 'getAllTask']);
```

**Laravel TaskController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
   
    public function getAllTask(){
        $task=Task::all();
        return response()->json(['allTask'=>$task],200);
    }


}
```

Answer (score -2):

Replace `http://` with `https://` in yoru axios request.

Try with this.

```
created(){
            this.axios.get("https://back.thecomicden.com/api/allTask").then(Response=>(this.tasks=Response.data.allTask))
        },
```